# Predefined files upload to web application (by HTML or different solution)

Tags: java, html, web, applet, webdav

On our company we have the solution inside web application where customer on web application can pre-define paths to files on disk (i.e: c:/invoices/summary.txt).

Afterwards by Java Applet we are reading files under defined paths to web application and modify the files on user disk.

Yes - here the problem appears - the Java Applets. The Chrome does not support it anymore and it is a legacy / unsecured solution. We are looking the replacement for this solution which allows us to modify the files on user disk and will support different Browsers / OS.

We considered the following solutions:

- dedicated external apps for OS which will be upload the defined files to our system (like Dropbox) but the problem is that we have to develop application for various OS and support it - a lot of work
- WebDav API and solution where customer download the script from web app and run it, script upload the files to server - the problem is that the script could be error prone
- HTML 5 solutions - we considered it but we want to achieve the situation that user defines the path only once

Does anyone see other sensible solutions for this case worth to try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to answer my own question. Finally as a team we decided to use the [WebDAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV) HTTP protocol extension. We wanted to avoid develop separate application for various systems (cost) and we needed solution which could be fast replaced in place of Java Applets.

After first test on QA I have to say that WebDAV solution works ok. Maybe the scripts for the client is not a best elegant solution but it works without bigger problems (after the client run the script he/she could observe the status on browser).

I could also suggest that anyone who will need separate application could consider the Dropbox API which allow to write/read files within Dropbox directory. The problem of maintenance separate application will be solved by Dropbox team :) Unfortunately we cannot do that due to our business domain but it also look as interesting way to deal with the problem.

I hope that answer will be helpful for someone in the future ;)

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using **Microsoft Silverlight** in place of Java applets. It has read-write access to local filesystem (only trusted ones). You can create silverlight app in Visual Studio which can run both as local application and as a web applet.

A simple code to write file in `C# (Silverlight 4)` would be

```
public void WriteFile(object sender, RoutedEventArgs event) {
    string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolerPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "TextFile.txt");

    /// or

    string other_path = "C:/invoices/summary.txt";

    StreamWriter writer;
    if (!File.Exists(path))
        writer = File.CreateText(path);

    writer.Write("Some text to write");
    writer.Close();
}
```

You can read more about creating trusted applications with silverlight.